# ¿Cómo puedo acomodar este arreglo mediante una función de ordenamiento?

Tags: java, array, ordenamiento

Tengo este codigo que es una lista de articulos con su codigo, nombre del articulo, precio, cantidad y la inversión (el resultado de la cantidad por el precio).
Quiero acomodarlo de manera ascendente solo tomando en cuenta el valor de la inversión.

import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    Articulos listaArticulos[] = new Articulos[3];

    listaArticulos[0] = new Articulos(001,"Azucar", 4, 4);
    listaArticulos[1] = new Articulos(002,"Atun  ", 3, 3);
    listaArticulos[2] = new Articulos(003,"Leche ", 2, 2);

    System.out.println("Orden según su monto de inversión");
    System.out.println("Codigo  Nombres    Precio  Cantidad  Inversion");
    for (int i = 0; i <listaArticulos.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(listaArticulos[i]);

    }
}
```

}

public class Articulos {

```
private String nombre;
private int precio;
private int cantidad;
private int codigo;

int inversion;


public Articulos(int codigo, String nombre, int precio, int cantidad) {
    this.codigo = codigo;
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.precio = precio;
    this.cantidad = cantidad;
    this.inversion = cantidad*precio;

}

public int getCodigo() {
    return codigo;
}

public void setCodigo(int codigo) {
    this.codigo = codigo;
}

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

public int getPrecio() {
    return precio;
}

public void setPrecio(int precio) {
    this.precio = precio;
}

public int getCantidad() {
    return cantidad;
}

public void setCantidad(int cantidad) {
    this.cantidad = cantidad;
}

public int getInversion() {
    return inversion;

}

public String toString() { return this.codigo + "        " + this.nombre + "     $" + this.precio + "      " + this.cantidad + "       " + this.inversion; }
```

}

Estoy intentado incorporar el método de la burbuja pero siempre me da error. ¿No es posible agregarlo o simplemente no lo estoy acomodando bien?

Answer (score 0):

Podes agregar una funcion o metodo estatico a la clase Articulo, que te permita ordenar un array de Articulos. El metodo usado es el burbuja:

```
public static Articulo[] sortArticulos(Articulo[] articulo){ // podemos usar una funcion estatica (una funcion no de la instancia, sino de la clase)
  Articulo flag;
  for (int i = 0; i < articulo.length; i++) // estos son 2 fors anidados aunque no tengan llaves, estan 1 dentro del otro
    for(int h = 0; h < articulo.length; h++) 
      if(articulo[i].getInversion()<articulo[h].getInversion()){ 
        flag = articulo[h];
        articulo[h] = articulo[i];
        articulo[i] = flag;
      }
  return articulo;
}
```

Eso lo colocas en la clase Articulo como cualquier otro metodo, y despues en el main:

```
public class Main { 
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Articulo[] listaArticulos = new Articulo[6];

    listaArticulos[0] = new Articulo(001,"Azucar", 10, 8);
    listaArticulos[1] = new Articulo(002,"Atun  ", 20, 30);
    listaArticulos[2] = new Articulo(003,"Leche ", 2, 2);
    listaArticulos[3] = new Articulo(004,"Huevo", 1, 1);
    listaArticulos[4] = new Articulo(005,"Pan  ", 3, 3);
    listaArticulos[5] = new Articulo(006,"Lomo ", 4, 1);

    // el array de articulos ahora es el array ordenado devuelto por la funcion de la clase Articulo
    listaArticulos = Articulo.sortArticulos(listaArticulos);

    // imprimimos usando toString y un bucle
    for(int i=0;i<listaArticulos.length;i++){
      System.out.println(listaArticulos[i].toString());
    }
  }
}
```

Ahí está ordenado de menor a mayor pero si quisieses que fuese al revés solo deberías cambiar `<` por `>` en el if. Puede que solo este fallando algo en tu algoritmo en si por eso tira el error.